# Spring MVC 3: Is consumes supposed to disambiguate request mappings?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have two request mappings in a Spring MVC 3 application, one which takes `json` and `xml`, and another that takes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/v1/foos"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json", "application/xml"})
public FooDTO createFoo(@RequestBody FooDTO requestDTO) throws Exception {
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value={"/v1/foos"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public FooDTO createFooWithForm(@ModelAttribute FooDTO requestDTO) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

I expected that the different `consumes` parameter makes each request unique, though I get an `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped...`.

Should `consumes` and `produces` makes requests unique?  Any ideas?

**Edit 1:** To add weight to this, if you set the `content-type` in the header rather than using `consumes`, this actually works and makes them unique: `headers="content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  Perhaps there is a bug with `consumes`?

**Edit 2:** We're using Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE.

Comment: Yeah, I believe so too, will see if anyone else can shed some light and then look at raising it as a bug with Spring.

Comment: I have got exact the same problem. Have you found the answer?

Comment: I could not find an answer to this and assume it must be a bug.

Comment: I've raised this on the Spring forums: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127184-Is-consumes-supposed-to-disambiguate-request-mappings&p=415042.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been resolved by Marten Deinum on the Spring Forum ([here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?127184-Is-consumes-supposed-to-disambiguate-request-mappings)):

> You should change both the HandlerMapping as well as the
>   HandlerAdapter (use the RequestMappingHandlerAdapter).
>
> In theory it should work if it doesn't feel free to register an issue.

The solution to this problem was to use the correct HandlerMapping and HandlerAdapter in my servlet configuration:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping"/>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter"/>
```

Thanks Marten.